# Run make without typing the path for make.exe

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, makefile

I am trying to learn C++, and I want to be able to compile my apps for Windows as well as OS X. It has been really easy to make a C++ app with Apple's xCode for OS X, but on my PC (with windows 10), I tried to use Eclipse. Having no experience with making Windows applications, I cannot seem to be able to build my hello world project. I keep getting this error in my console: `Error: Program "make" not found in PATH` and then it shows me a long string of paths where I think it is trying to find the file "make.exe".

I have tried installing make.exe, I have tried putting the path for "make.exe" in the path string (which kind of worked because it showed the path for "make.exe" in the error), but I have not even been able to build my project. When I type into Command Prompt `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe"`, I have some success, but when I run `make`, it says `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I need to know step by step exactly what links I need to go to or what I need to type into Command Prompt to be able to build my C++ projects because I am completely new to this subject.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've run a Windows system, but try adding the entire folder to `PATH`, as in:  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\"`.  Also try switching those back-slashes to forward slashes; they might need to be escaped otherwise.  In other words, try adding `"C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/"` to `PATH`.

Comment: Adding the entire folder to `PATH` did the trick, thanks!